# $(document).ready function will not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a very simple HTML document with an even less complex `$(document).ready()` function. However.... nothing in the function will fire. I've set alerts and breakpoints (in Chrome's debugger) and nothing works. Below is the markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" />
<script>
    alert('outside');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('here');
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Neither alerts work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Is this all the code? it seems like it was cut in the middle - or maybe this is the problem :)

Comment: My apologies, I assumed it went w/o saying that I had closed the tags (my mistake). @SLaks - No, I don't get any errors in the console at all. The page loads without incident.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" />` to

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The concept of self-closing tags is an XML concept. You can't use them in HTML. (You can use them in XHTML, but only if the document is served with an XML content-type, not if it is served as text/html).

In HTML some elements (such as <img>) cannot have any content, so they don't have end tags).

Since a script can have a src attribute or the script be can inside the element, <script> is not one of them.

(HTML 5 allows a / character to appear at the end of a start tag for an element that is defined as EMPTY, but it is just sugar for people addicted to XML and has no meaning in the language)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
alert('outside');
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('here');
});
</script>
```

you forgot to close the arches. and the closing tag of script.

Comment: Well, if this is the case then he also forgot to close `</script>`, `</head>`, and even `</html>`...

Comment: Updated the code. I had simply left out the closing tags from the post.